# Filling a column with References to another column in reverse order

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am trying to fill a column with data from another column using a reference to that column's data. I know how to do this normally, but today I need to fill in the reverse order. Row 2, needs to contain the data from row 70, and Row 3 the data in Row 69, for example. I have (somehow) accomplished this before but today excel insists on always filling in increasing order. I have tried filling bottom up (same result) And no, I cannot just reorder the other column. To complicate things (only a little) further, it looks more like this:

```
Sheets("Sheet 1").Rows(2).Value = Sheets("Sheet 2").Rows(70).Value / Sheets("Sheet 3").Rows(70).Value
```

I am not trying to do this VBA at the moment, just using coding syntax for descriptive purposes. However, if this can be done better VBA that is fine too!

Thanks!

Comment: you can use the row of Sheet 2 and Sheet 3 by using (70 - Sheet1's row + 2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use through formula, you can use the below formula to copy the value from column A of both Sheet 2 an SHeet3

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!A:A,70+2-ROW(),1)/INDEX(Sheet3!A:A,70+2-ROW(),1)
```